# Using ACF image field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have used some JavaScript on a previous site and would like to re-use the effect - the effect being a background image on a div changes when hovering over various links.

However this time, I want the images to be ACF fields. I have read through the JavaScript API documentation and other posts but I can't get it to work.

This is what I have. I think maybe I have correctly fetched the field but need to add the action of showing it on hover.

Each table cell on the left is an ACF field that consists of a title, description, link and image. I want the large image on the right to change to the ACF image applied to each cell when each one is hovered over.

I have included my attempts, though I have very limited php/js knowledge so it's likely not even close. I am also new to ACF.

[Link here](https://www.newbattle-abbey.shereewalker.com/)

Attempt 1

```
const defaultImg = "/wp-content/default-image.jpg";
const newImg = acf.getField('featured_item_one_image');
const newImgb = acf.getField('featured_item_two_image');


$('.feat-block-1')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.main-image').css('background-image', "url(" + newImg + ")");
  })


$('.feat-block-2')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.main-image').css('background-image', "url(" + newImgb + ")");
  })
```

Attempt 2

```
const newImg = acf.getField('field_5de5a95617941');
const newImgb = acf.getField('field_5de5abd20cb3f');


$('.feat-block-1')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.main-image').css('background-image', "url(" + newImg + ")");
  })

  $('.feat-block-2')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.main-image').css('background-image', "url(" + newImgb + ")");
  })
```

And Also this without any of the 'const' values at the top

```
$('.feat-block-1')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.main-image').css('background-image', "acf.getField('field_5de5abd20cb3f')");
  })

  $('.feat-block-2')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.main-image').css('background-image', "acf.getField('field_5de5abd20cb3f')");  })
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: why don't you get variables from php and generate inline css? 
simply you can set background image with `presudo-selector` `.feat-block-1:hover`

Comment: I think the ACF JS API need the field key, not the selector.

Comment: @AliQorbani I'm not 100% Sure what you mean. I want the client to be able to simply be able to pick an image with the ACF image field and the rest is automated.

Comment: @Stender yes I think you are right - I amended it but no luck. I will add the effort to the original question.

Comment: @MrToad, There is jQuery error : _Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function_
in the link you have shared. To fix that wrap your script inside jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // your code goes here

}); and then check if your code works or not.

Comment: @anujpatel Thanks for your help - I have just amended this but it seems to have flagged up more errors.

Comment: @anujpatel Have I not done this correctly?

Comment: @MrToad, Look for javascript error in browser console.Currently in console it gives _ReferenceError: acf is not defined_ javascript error, this is because acf js is not enqueued correctly. You can check this link https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-input-admin_enqueue_scripts/ for fixing issue.Let me know how it help you.

Comment: Hi there - I am even more confused now :(

So I have added

`function my_acf_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
 
    
    // register script
    wp_register_script( 'acf-custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/acf-custom.js', false, '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'acf-custom-js' );
    
}

add_action( 'acf/input/admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_acf_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
`
to my functions php but it doesn't seem to fetch the fetch at all OR show any errors?

Comment: There is no javascript error in console now.Further,javascript API provided by ACF can be used for the purpose of wordpress admin backend customizations. I suggest you to try different approach as suggested below in answer given by @krishna-savani.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this before but in different way see below code:

1) I have used Advance Custom field Repeater plugin [pluginlike](https://github.com/wab/acf-repeater) i have installed that and make custom fields with that see here (https://prnt.sc/q6yohq)

2) insert the value in page from admin 
e.g i want this value "stackoverflowpage" page(i have made template )so from admin i will insert the value see here(https://prnt.sc/q6yqak)

3) In template file (.php) i have inserted below code 
**I have take image value in input type hidden in bg-image by id so i can use later in jquery to show image on hover**

```
<?php

    if( have_rows('allfields') ): ?>
    <?php 
    $i=1;
    while( have_rows('allfields') ): the_row(); 

        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('image');
        $title = get_sub_field('title');
        $content = get_sub_field('description');
        $link = get_sub_field('link');

        ?>
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td >
        <div id="slides_<?php echo $i ?>"  class="divcommonclass">
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%" class="home-featured-heading">
        <h4>
        <a href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $title; ?>                                             </a>
                                                                                        </h4>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%" class="home-featured-heading">
        <?php echo $content; ?>         
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="bg-image" value="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php $i++; 
         endwhile; ?>
         <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="imageshow"></div>
```

4) give style to div where we want to show image

```
<style>
  .imageshow {
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-image: url('http://localhost/stackoverflow/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/person_2.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
    }
</style>
```

5) add this script to show image when hover on block

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.divcommonclass')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
  var id =  $(this).attr('id');
    var imagpath = $('#'+id+ "+ #bg-image").val();

    $('.imageshow').css('background-image', "url(" + imagpath + ")");
  });

});
</script>
```

**I did not use of javascript to get image value of acf javascript and show in div for that i have just used inut type hidden and add value there and in javascript i have just get that image value by its id**

**Output** : please download and check video(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xTmSBlxn9NW0Klc4l-uOdA_l---oHuV7/view)

Comment: Hi Krishna, thank you very much for taking the time to answer this and sorry it took so long to come back to you.

So I have tried implementing your answer. I switched my field to a repeater (I had custom fields pro installed so I really should have used that to start with but I'm still learning).

I have implemented the rest but I can't seem to get it to work. I get a console error

'Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function'

I'm unsure what I am doing wrong

Comment: It's working!
I switched it to jQuery(document).ready(function($){
Thank you very much for your help! I've awarded you the bounty :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have hit a caveat in that to apply my custom hover effects, I had to apply the link to entire block, other wise it was super glitchy. This has stopped the image swap from working.

Is there any way to apply the link to the divs .featured-item-singular, not the .divcommonclass?

Though I think I need to actually combine effects as I already have this `jQuery(".featured-item-singular").mouseover(function(){
  jQuery(".donut").addClass("donut-show");
});


jQuery(".featured-item-singular").mouseleave(function(){
 jQuery(".donut").removeClass("donut-show");
});
`

Comment: I have managed to get it to work but I'm fairly sure it's not done properly as I have used the id twice - which is the only way it will work but I thought you couldn't sue an id twice?

You can see it here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yd1up4ffaqy3thc/home-page%202.php?dl=0

Comment: @MrToad  by mouse over in link text i have update the code see (https://www.dropbox.com/s/2b966pyq4eylkqg/template-stackpage.php?dl=0)